# Why does Properties.list copy table before printing?

Tags: java, collections

Here's the implementation of `Properties.list` from JDK:

```
public void list(PrintWriter out) {
    out.println("-- listing properties --");
    Hashtable<String,Object> h = new Hashtable<>();
    enumerate(h);
    for (Enumeration<String> e = h.keys() ; e.hasMoreElements() ;) {
        String key = e.nextElement();
        String val = (String)h.get(key);
        if (val.length() > 40) {
            val = val.substring(0, 37) + "...";
        }
        out.println(key + "=" + val);
    }
}
```

What are the lines

```
Hashtable<String,Object> h = new Hashtable<>();
enumerate(h);
```

for? Couldn't it just use original table instead of making a copy and reading data from it?

Comment: Gerald Mücke's answer (currently deleted) is correct. The reason has to do with a `Properties` object having a set of defaults, which are themselves `Properties` objects, which in turn can have defaults. Entries later in the default chain are screened by earlier ones. The `enumerate` method recursively flattens the entries into a single table, which is then printed out. Making a flattened copy is the most straightforward way of implementing the semantics of defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `list()` method is not synchronized. 
So any invocation (even those synchronized) on the `Properties` instance  during `list()` invocation may break the state of the object and result to an exception or a broken logic.

Suppose that instead using an intermediate Properties instance, we iterate directly on the `Properties` instance it would be no thread safe

Suppose that we have two threads : Thread A that calls this `list()` method and Thread B that calls `remove()` on a same `Properties` instance.

This code in the `list()` method has multiple race conditions.

To illustrate, we could use this snippet of the list() method :

```
   String key = e.nextElement();
   String val = (String)h.get(key);
   if (val.length() > 40) {
```

Suppose the thread A is paused after this instruction :

```
 String key = e.nextElement();
```

The thread B is resumed and invokes `instance.remove()` with as parameter the object associated to the key retrieved by the Thread A

Then when the thread A is resumed it goes to the next instruction :

```
 String val = (String)h.get(key);
```

The value doesn't exist any longer.

The next instruction raises an exception as val is `null` :

```
    if (val.length() > 40) {
```

Comment: The hashtable `h` is a snapshot of the state of Properties when `enumerate` was called. It is a different hashtable to any table that thread B could be using. There is no risk that h.get(key) would fail.

Comment: @Klitos Kyriacou I know. It is my bad.  I was not specific enough in the form. I updated.It is good ?

Answer (score 2):

It's a common idiom to allow thread-safe iteration (i.e. no `ConcurrentModificationException` that could arise if another thread is modifying the hashtable during the loop).

Comment: This is a bit misleading: remember that ConcurrentModificationException has nothing to do with thread safety in general.

Comment: I don't see how it's misleading, it's a very common symptom of a race condition (side effect from another thread) during a critical section (enumerate iteration). "nothing to do with thread safety" is quite streching it...

Answer (score 1):

This is an optimization for multithreaded applications.

A `Properties` object is meant to be thread safe, so they had to either make the method synchronized (which is a bad idea since writing to a `PrintStream` can block for a long time, holding the lock), or they can just quickly copy the contents to a new hashtable within a synchronized block (`enumerate` is synchronized), and then printing the items of the copy, without holding a lock.